# problem in accessing the anonymous class method

Tags: java

I have written this code and this generate the error like Illegal start of expression on the line of run() method ,please solve my problem.

```
     class Reentrant 
        {
            public synchronized void m() 
            {
                 n();  
                    System.out.println("this is m() method");  
                }  


            public synchronized void n() 
            {  
                    System.out.println("this is n() method");  
                }
            {  
                public void run(){  
                        m();//calling method of Reentrant class  
                }  
            };  
        }  
        class ReentrantExample
        {  
            public static void main(String args[])
            {  
                Reentrant re=new Reentrant();  

                Thread t1=new Thread();

                t1.start();  
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have a `}` before the `run` method that needs to be removed it seems.

Comment: remove the { and }; that you've put around that method

Comment: This braces is for starting of Anonymous class

Comment: @JackFlamp a {, actually, and a closing one after it. if you remove the } before run, you'll try to put a block and a method inside another method

Comment: I have to call the method which is inside the anonymous class

Comment: @Yogesh that might be your intent, but it's not the syntax of an anonymous class, but of a block. Check this link for more information on anonymous classes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: @Stultuske ok, I didn't spend too much time looking at it :)

Comment: @Stultuske ok, can you tell me that can i write the run() method inside the main() method.Is there any restriction regarding this in java

Comment: you can't declare methods inside methods. sure, you can create an anonymous class which contains them, just not directly

Answer (score 1):

Change your code,

> ```
> {  
>             public void run(){  
>                     m();//calling method of Reentrant class  
>             }  
>         };
> ```

to

```
  public void run(){  
                    m();//calling method of Reentrant class  
            }
```

Comment: how is this using an anonymous class?